# The chart gets the wrong months using laravel /ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, charts

I'm trying to display data on a chart using laravel.

So I'm using the following code :

Controller :

```
$contrats_par_mois = Contrat::select(\DB::raw("COUNT(*) as count"))
                    ->whereYear('date_signature', date('Y'))
                    ->groupBy(\DB::raw("Month(date_signature)"))
                    ->pluck('count');
```

My view :

```
<div class="card-body">
     <h5 class="card-title">Sales</h5>
     <div id="container"></div>
 </div>
```

Script :

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var contrats_par_mois = <?php echo json_encode($contrats_par_mois)?>;
     var d = new Date();
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        title: {
            text: 'Contrats Par mois'
        },
       
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Janvier', 'Février', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juillet', 'Aout', 'Septembre',
                'Octobre', 'Novembre', 'Décembre'
            ]
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Nombre de contrats'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                allowPointSelect: true
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Nombre de contrats',
            data: contrats_par_mois
        }],
        responsive: {
            rules: [{
                condition: {
                    maxWidth: 500
                },
                chartOptions: {
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'horizontal',
                        align: 'center',
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    });

</script>
```

The problem is it gets the wrong month , the `count` information is correct but it display the `wrong month`.

For example in my database I have the following dates :

```
2021-08-07 , 2021-06-01
```

But in the chart I'm getting :

[image]

I should get in my chart : Juin and Aout instead of Janvier et février

If you have any idea , please help

**UPDATE**

The output of `dd($contrats_par_mois);` :

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1474 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => 6
    1 => 1
  ]
}
```

Comment: It would help alot if we could se what contrats_par_mois looks like

Comment: please check my update

Comment: You don't pass any month in the data, so how should it know what month/dates are associated with those values.

Comment: This might give you an idea https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=41852

Comment: But how can I pass the month in the data ?

Answer (score 1):

I resolve it by change my controller to :

```
 $year = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
                   $contrats_par_mois=DB::table('contrats')
                 ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as count'), DB::raw('MONTH(date_signature) as month'))
                 ->groupBy('month')
                 ->get();


                foreach($contrats_par_mois as $key){
                   $year[$key->month-1] = $key->count;

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your dates have an incorrect format, you could try several things, fix your dates to match what is required in your chart, or format your dates in JavaScript before passing the variable contrats_par_mois to the series data.

First I would see the actual data in the console, so you could do this after this variable and check how the dates are coming:

```
var contrats_par_mois = <?php echo json_encode($contrats_par_mois)?>;
console.log(contrats_par_mois);
```

After this you can check in your console in the dev tools to see the actual results of the dates, if the dates looks like "12-12-2000 August blabla", it won't work, I think the graph expects a specific date.

Another thing I would first try, is to pass your data in your JavaScript first, so something like:

```
var contrats_par_mois = [{'02-12-2000', 'Février'}, {'12-12-2000', 'Décembre'}];
```

Just to check if that's how the graph needs the series of the data to be delivered, trial and error until you get the correct dates into the graph.

Comment: thank you very much for ur answer : when I did `console.log(contrats_par_mois)` I get `(2) [6, 1]0: 61: 1length: 2[[Prototype]]: Array(0)` , I passed only the count information to my view , I don't know how can I pass also the month of the date